# subproof from theorem of Polya

Tags: polynomials, proof-writing

Suppose we have polynomial:

> $$f(z) = z^n + b_{n-1}z^{n-1} + \cdots + b_0$$

It is a complex polynomial of degree $\geq 1$ with leading coefficient $1$. Associate with $f(z)$ set:

> $$C := \{z \in \Bbb{C} \,:\, |f(z)| \leq 2\}$$

Now, how do I prove, that for $f(z) = z^2 - 2$ we have $x + iy\in C$ if and only if:

> $$(x^2 + y^2)^2 \leq 4(x^2 - y^2)$$

It should follow that $x^4\leq(x^2 + y^2)^2\leq 4x^2$ and thus $x^2\leq 4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let us simplify what we are looking for without substituting in for $z$.

$$\left| z^2-2 \right|\leq 2 \Leftrightarrow (z^2-2)(\overline{z}^2-2) \leq 4 \Leftrightarrow \left|z \right|^4-2(z^2+\overline{z}^2)+4 \leq 4 \Leftrightarrow (\left|z \right|^2)^2 \leq 4 \operatorname{Re}(z^2). $$

Now plugging in $z=x+iy$, we have

$$(x^2+y^2)^2\leq 4 \operatorname{Re}(x+iy)^2 = 4 \operatorname{Re}(x^2-y^2+2ixy)=4(x^2-y^2) $$
which gives the desired inequality.

Comment: Re(z) means real part of complex z?

Comment: @MilošLukačka  Yes.